# AngularJS confirmation modal custom action on No/Cancel button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-angularjs-modal-service

I am using the above blog post as a guide to build the confirmation modal service in my Angular app. If I may ask, does anyone know how can the service be modified to support a custom action on the Cancel/No button in addition to dismissing the modal?

At the moment, the code only supports custom actions on the Yes button. I am having trouble understanding this part of the service code whereby I am not sure what the variable "result" actually is and how the functions can be modified to return something when the No/Cancel button is clicked:

```
$scope.modalOptions.ok = function (result) {
    $modalInstance.close(result);
};
$scope.modalOptions.close = function (result) {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

Next is the code for invoking the modal from the controller.

```
var modalOptions = {
    closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
    actionButtonText: 'Yes',
    headerText: 'Delete',
    bodyText: 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?'
};

modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions)
.then(
    function (result) {
        //custom actions for Yes button here
    }
);
```

In other words, when I invoke the modal in the controller, how do I intercept the flow after user clicks on the No/Cancel button on the modal?

I tried doing something like this and it didn't work.

```
modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions)
.then(
    function (result) {
       //custom actions for Yes button here
    }, 
    function (result) {
       //custom actions for No button here
    }
 );
```

Comment: In the first function(result) you need to call the promise result.close or result.dismiss.